# Do WebEx's requirements open security holes?

Tags: appsec, browser-extensions, cisco, uac, install

After a WebEx presentation is recorded, the recording cannot be played in-browser without installing a browser extension that requires invasive permissions to access the user's data for all websites:

[image: Add Cisco WebEx Extension? It requires your permission to access your data for all websites and exchange messages with programs other than Firefox.]

There is no "temporary application" option as there is when trying to join a WebEx meeting in progress.

As an alternative, the user sending the recording can download the video, but it's in an ARF or WRF format that can't be played without first installing proprietary [software](https://www.webex.com/play-webex-recording.html) that requires root/administrative access to the full machine.

Theoretically, it is not necessary for WebEx to have administrative control in order to play a video, and it could be that this requirement is opening security holes for Cisco et al. to exploit and get information they shouldn't have access to.

What is the reasoning behind this requirement?
Is it a significant security issue to be concerned about?
Have there been independent examinations of the software to verify that the software is not (or is) doing more than it claims to?

Comment: *"...verify that the software is not (or is) doing more than it claims to?..."* - seriously, this whole WebEx is kind of like flash in regard of security issues. For example from last year [Cisco WebEx Browser Extension Remote Code Execution Vulnerability](https://tools.cisco.com/security/center/content/CiscoSecurityAdvisory/cisco-sa-20170717-webex) or from this year [Cisco WebEx Clients Remote Code Execution Vulnerability](https://tools.cisco.com/security/center/content/CiscoSecurityAdvisory/cisco-sa-20180418-wbs) - both critical.